# Which ending/route does Aoi Shiro - Kaeishou adapt?

Tags: aoishiro

I recently did a search on Manga Updates for Shoujo Ai, and to my surprise I found a bunch of Aoishiro manga.

According to Manga Updates, [Aoi Shiro - Kaeishou](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=20501) is the official manga, but I am wondering which route/ending from the Visual Novel it adapts and if there are any significant changes to it (i.e. choosing one route while taking elements from other routes, like what the Fate/Stay Night anime did with taking elements from Unlimited Blade Works and Heaven's Feel Routes for it's adaptation of the Fate Route).

Comment: I changed "Fate/Stay Night anime" to manga, since it seems to fit your description.

Comment: @nhahtdh i haven't read the manga and used "anime" because i knew it did fit with what i was trying to saying. Rin and Shirou's fight in the school, the discovery of Caster's Master and her attempt to prematurely summon the lesser grail are taken from the Unlimited Blade Works route (in Fate she just appears breifly only to be killed by Gilgamesh), Also while not dressed the same, Sakura's attacks and Rin's embrace of her is from Heaven's Feel.  i'm am unsure what changes there are in the Manga in the route it chooses to adapt